# Laravel Migration: auto increment key when it is not primary

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

I'm trying to create a table with Laravel migrations but I'm having some trouble.
I just need to create a table with a primary pair ('id' and 'revision'), being 'id' an auto increment.
I can do it in MySQL, but I can't manage to do it with Laravel Migrations since increments() also set the field as primary.
So far I have this:

```
Schema::create('bibliographies', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('revision');
        ...
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->primary(array('id', 'revision'));
    });
```

Note: changing increments() method is not an option since it is Laravel core.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just [drop the primary key](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#dropping-indexes) before you re-add it:

```
$table->dropPrimary( 'id' );
$table->primary( array( 'id', 'revision' ) );
```

Comment: I had already tried but with no success. It returns me this error:

   [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                            
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto  
   column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: alter table `bibliographies` drop primary key)

Also, the table is created with only 'id' as primary key and I need to manually drop it.

Comment: @CarlosMaia Assuming you don't actually need a pair of columns to be **primary**, you can make them [unique](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_unique) without any problem at all - would that work?

Comment: @Joe, I am facing the same problem. But I don't want to make my other columns unique and also not primary. What to do?

Comment: @MASh I'm not sure I understand what you're asking

Comment: @MASh StackExchange 101: When you solve your problem, tell everyone else so they can learn too. It's not a one-way street - you should be giving back to the community too. HOW did you solve your problem?

Comment: @MASh could let me know how did you solve this problem, i'm stuck here and i can't find a way to solve the issue(I want to keep my composite key)

Answer (score 3):

```
 $table->unsignedInteger('id')->change();//will remove the auto increment
 $table->dropPrimary('id');//will remove primary constrain
 $table->unsignedInteger('revision') //add revision column
 $table->primary( array( 'id', 'revision' ) );//make them both primary
 $table->increments('id')->change()//add the auto increment constrain back
```